# Custom redirect after backend form save

Tags: octobercms

Its possible to set the `redirect` and `redirectClose` attributes in the form configuration file to use custom redirects in create and update pages in the backend.

But is it possible to conditionally change where the user is redirected after form save? Lets say based on some GET parameters.

Maybe somehow in the controller? Or create/update view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override Controller functions create_onSave, update_onSave like that

```
public function create_onSave($context = null)
{
    parent::create_onSave($context);

    return \Backend::redirect($your_custom_url);
}
```

Comment: Damn...the simplest solutions are always the hardest to figure out :D
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way (in your controller):

```
public function formGetRedirectUrl($context = null, $model = null)
{
    if (\Request::get('param') == 'param_value') { // or you can use strpos(\Request::path(),'your/parameter') if you want to filter path segments
        return 'your/backend/url';
    }

    return parent::formGetRedirectUrl($context, $model);
}
```